# I am trying to update a collection minted with a Candy Machine to the MIP-1 standard

Tags: solana-program, metaplex

I created a collection using the latest Sugar CLI tool about a month ago, and am getting an error when trying to upgrade the collection to the MIP-1 standard.  The first collection (the one giving me issues) is currently being protected by Simpl3r, could that be the issue?

A second collection that was created yesterday is in the 14 day waiting period.  Please see the below image

[image: error message]

Comment: Did you try again later?
Is there an error shown in the browser console?
Can you tell us the collection address?

Comment: I did try a few times a few days apart.  Of course, the day after I posted this it worked successfully. TYSM @MarkSackerberg for putting the "fear of support" into the program :) 

I had the browser console open this time to try and catch the error

Cheers!

SOLVED!